# Excel 2010 vba array as a class member error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project and have run into something that I don't understand.  When assigning an array to a class member, the `Let` and `Get` names cannot be the same.  If they are, I get the error:

`Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter`

Can anyone tell me if I'm just doing something wrong, or if this is just how it is.  The code below generates the above message.

Test Code:

```
Sub loadServer()
Dim testServer As AvayaServer
Dim i As Long
Dim arr() As Variant

arr = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

Set testServer = New AvayaServer
testServer.Name = "This Sucks"
testServer.Skill = arr
MsgBox testServer.Skills(4)
MsgBox testServer.Name

End Sub
```

Class Code:

```
Private pName As String
Private pSkills() As String
Public Property Get Skills() As Variant
Skills = pSkills()
End Property

Public Property Let Skills(values() As Variant)
ReDim pSkills(UBound(values))
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    pSkills(i) = values(i)
Next
End Property
```

Comment: change `values() As Variant` to `values As Variant`

Comment: @simoco Thank you!  I knew I had to be missing something silly

Comment: @vbnoob it is indeed silly (the thing, not you missing it) - a bizarre quirk. `values As Variant` will be a Variant which you later use to store an array, `values() As Variant` is an array of Variants. The Array function can only be assigned to the former. Also I assume `testServer.Skill` (note no "s") is just a spelling mistake above. If it isn't then change your code and I suggest putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, the `testServer.Skill` was there only by partial intent.  Originally, for the code to work that in conjunction with `Let Skill(values() As Variant` had to be used.  It really was an oversight in the post since I didn't correct all of the code.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `values() As Variant` to `values As Variant`:

**Class Code:**

```
Private pName As String
Private pSkills() As String
Public Property Get Skills() As Variant
Skills = pSkills()
End Property

Public Property Let Skills(values As Variant)          'Fixed here
ReDim pSkills(UBound(values))
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    pSkills(i) = values(i)
Next
End Property
```

**Explanation:**

`values As Variant` will be of type `Variant`, which you later use to store an array.
`values() As Variant` is an array of type `Variant`, to which an `Array` cannot be assigned; an `Array` can only be assigned to the former.

Comment: Just collating comments from the question as these answered the question. Not claiming this as my own work.